# Why is Maven not finding this jar

Tags: java, maven

I have the following JAR that my project needs so I added it to my pom.xml...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.reficio</groupId>
        <artifactId>soap-builder</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
                <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But when I run Maven it tries to download from various repos and finally fails. It only creates a "lastUpdated" file whose contents are below..

```
http\://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/.lastUpdated=1392941827625
http\://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases/.lastUpdated=1392941828195
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is this JAR simply not there anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: WHere are you specifying whatever repository that's in? Because it isn't in maven central.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That artefact isn't in Maven Central (or other default repo) and so Maven won't find it automatically.  The [`reficio/soap-ws` page on Github](https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws) explains:

> `soap-ws` is not yet located in the central maven repo, thus you also have to add an additional repository to your config.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>reficio</id>
        <url>http://repo.reficio.org/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but the url is down, can't download any suggest?